# python regexp parse

Tags: python, regex

I have hash:

```
{'login': u'myemail (myemail@gmail.com)'}
```

I need parse only email `myemail@gmail.com`

What regexp I must compose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No regex is needed. Use string manipulation instead.  This will split the value on the first space, then strip the `()` from the second item (`[1]`) of the returned array.

```
yourhash = {'login': u'myemail (myemail@gmail.com)'}

email = yourhash['login'].split()[1].strip("()")

print(email)
# myemail@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really need a regular expression solution (versus the excellent string split options also posted) this will do it for you:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.match('.*\((.*)\)', 'myemail (myemail@gmail.com)').group(1)
'myemail@gmail.com'
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use string methods instead:

```
my_dict['login'].split['('][1].strip(')')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many patterns for matching emails.  A good resource can be found [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html).

For example,

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$
```